# Banner Ad placement in a mobile app

Tags: mobile, applications, advertisement

Where should you put banner advertising in a mobile app?

Specifically take this mockup for example.

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/A8HcBC7CQAEuQnd.png:large

Above title? Below title?
Below navbar? Above navbar?

I understand that putting ads near buttons is bad, but that axiom does not leave me with many options.

---

EDIT with Rachel's suggestion:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIo9A.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like mobile banner ads (I prefer interstitials), but I'd put them up at the top of the screen.

Least likely to get in the way of a clicking user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to throw this out for consideration:

Place full-width horizontal ad bars above any bottom-docked tab bars.
I have seen this placement used in many apps on iOS, but in that case, there is no row of virtual buttons.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/99TSb.jpg

One obvious argument against this is it almost starts looking like too many horizontal bars on the bottom.

But two benefits:

1. any input fields and the keyboard can immediately overlap it, no concern about even less space for app. (like Megachip said)
2. **it doesn't permanently crush your whole app's usable screen real estate**, like you'd experience with extreme top or extreme bottom.  You can choose to hide it when you feel you need to, and use that space for other content.

I'm a big fan of #2 so it's bolded :)

Answer (score 0):

Also prefer the way, Rachel recommended it.

But most apps placed it on the bottom, simply cause if your app had any input fields and the keyboard pops up or down (to fast or to slow), the user accidentally clicks on the ad. So you can generate much clicks but i absolutely dislike that way, cause some apps are inuseable cause of this.

Also the way your eyes moves is from top to bottom, so an ad on the top will be recognized at first.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a mockup yourself with your ideas. I agree with what you say, so having the app's buttons away from the banner and keeping the banner on top... this way you ensure that no unintended clicks and frustration derived from it happen while clicking those buttons :)

Comment: Accidental clicks are bad for ux. Ads are bad enough as it is, I don't want to make my app frustrating to use.